# How to select the first item in a CollectionViewSource when its source collection has been changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having a problem while using full XAML code.

To keep it simple, here are the view models I have:

```
public class MyItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _index;

    public int Index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set { RaisePropertyChanged("Index"); }
    }
}

public class MyCollectionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> Items { get; }
}
```

My control is bound to `MyCollectionViewModel`, and I'm using a `CollectionViewSource` to synchronize my selected item:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MyWpfApplication.MyControl">
    <!-- The DataContext of the UserControl is MyCollectionViewModel -->
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyView" Source="{Binding Items}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
            <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
                <s:String>Index</s:String>
            </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="Index" Direction="Ascending" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyView}}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index, StringFormat={}Item #{0}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

        <local:MyItemControl DataContext="{Binding /}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my problem:

- When `MyControl` is displayed while `MyCollectionViewModel.Items` contains 1 or more elements, the 1st one is automatically selected and `MyItemControl` is displayed accordingly. Everything is fine and excpected
- But when `MyControl` is displayed while `MyCollectionViewModel.Items` contains no items, no item is selected. If one item is added to the list while `MyControl` is displayed, the selection (i.e. the current item of the `CollectionViewSource`) does not change.

Is there any way I could achieve this: select the newly added item if there is no selection yet?

I could write some code-behind logic, but I try to avoid that. I also try to avoid creating `ICollectionView` instances in my view models. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: you can take advantage of `Items.OnCollectionChanged` event, and set the `CollectionViewSource.SelectedItem ` to `Items.First()` if `Items.Count() > 0`, else set to `null`. If this isn't a solution for you, I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion k1dev, but I try to avoid using code behind and hooking to events. Also, there is no `SelectedItem` field in the `CollectionViewSource` class...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042217/confused-about-collectionviewsource-selecteditem-not-working-in-combos

Comment: Yeah that's not related to my issue... In my case selection is synchronized, I'm only trying to automatically select the first item of my collection if there is no selection and an item has been added to the collection. But thanks for helping me out anyway!

Comment: @edupeux
The "code behind" can be implemented in an attached property; then it's controllable by XAML and reusable in other places. See https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/common-information/mvvm-helpers/common-attached-behaviors

Comment: Hi @BatteryBackupUnit, this question is pretty old now. Thanks for the suggestion, but now in my view models I have the ObservableCollection, and another property bound to the ComboBox selected item. This way, I can control this easily in my view models.